# Spring 4 Security + CORS + AngularJS - Weird redirect

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security, cors

I am having issues with my Spring backend and an AngularJS frontend. As an info, I'm pretty new to Spring Security and learning with this project as well.

I'm not using SpringBoot. Both work seperately and are supposed to be able to run on seperate machines. ATM my frontend is running locally via gulp server on **`https://localhost:3000`**, the backend is running in a Tomcat at **`https://localhost:8443/context`**. I've set up a `CORSFilter` in Java.

So far, so good. If I start the frontend, calls are being made to the backend for getting resources and I'm seing the login page. If I choose login, the call is being made to `https://localhost:8443/context/login`, as its supposed to. **But**: After the login is being processed in the backend, the backend does a redirect to **`https://localhost:8443/context`** instead of **`https://localhost:3000`**, which of course creates a 404 and results in a failed login (frontend-wise). I just can't find where this weird redirect is being made.

**`SpringSecurityConfig`**:

```java
private static final String C440_LOGIN = "/login";
private static final String c440_START_PAGE = "/index.html";
private static final String FAVICON_ICO = "/favicon.ico";

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // HttpSecurity workHttp = http.addFilterBefore(new CORSFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class); does not work!
    HttpSecurity workHttp = http.addFilterBefore(new CORSFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
    workHttp.addFilterBefore(new CookieFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
    workHttp.addFilterBefore(getUsernamePasswordPortalAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    // set authorizations
    workHttp = authorizeRequests(http);
    // login handling
    workHttp = formLogin(workHttp);
    // exception handling
    workHttp = exceptionHandling(workHttp);
    // logout handling
    workHttp = logout(workHttp);
    // cookie handling
    workHttp = rememberMe(workHttp);

    // disable caching because if IE11 webfonds bug
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748140/font-face-eot-not-loading-over-https
    http.headers().cacheControl().disable();

    csrf(workHttp);
}

/**
 * Configures request authorization.
 *
 * @param http The security configuration.
 * @return The configured security configuration.
 * @throws Exception is throws if the configuration fails.
 */
protected HttpSecurity authorizeRequests(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
        .authorizeRequests()

        // secured pages
        .antMatchers("/", getCustomerdWebRessourceSecuredPath()).authenticated()

        // common resources
        .antMatchers("/app/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/profiles/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/captcha/**").permitAll()

        .antMatchers("/", getCustomerRessourcePath()).permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/", getCustomerWebRessourcePath()).permitAll()

        .antMatchers("/", c440_START_PAGE).permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/", FAVICON_ICO).permitAll()
        .antMatchers(C440_LOGIN).permitAll()

        // frontend services
        .antMatchers("/services/userService/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/services/applicationService/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/services/textContentService/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/services/textContentBlockService/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/services/menuItemService/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/services/calculatorService/**").permitAll()

        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and();
}

private String getCustomerRessourcePath() {
    return "/resources/app-" + portalFrontendBase + "/**";
}

private String getCustomerWebRessourcePath() {
    return "/app-" + portalFrontendBase + "/**";
}

private String getCustomerdWebRessourceSecuredPath() {
    return "/app-" + portalFrontendBase + "/secure/**";
}

/**
 * Configures form login.
 *
 * @param http The security configuration.
 * @return The configured security configuration.
 * @throws Exception is throws if the configuration fails.
 */
protected HttpSecurity exceptionHandling(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
            if (authException != null) {
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                /**
                 * IMPORTANT: do not redirect the requests. The front-end will be responsible to do this.
                 * Otherwise the unauthorized status cannot be caught in the front-end correctly.
                 */
                return;
            }
        })
        .and();
}

/**
 * Configures form login.
 *
 * @param http The security configuration.
 * @return The configured security configuration.
 * @throws Exception is throws if the configuration fails.
 */
protected HttpSecurity formLogin(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage(c440_START_PAGE)
            .successHandler(getAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
            .failureHandler(getAuthenticationFailureHandler())
            .loginProcessingUrl(C440_LOGIN)
            .permitAll()
            .and();
}

/**
 * Configures logout.
 *
 * @param http The security configuration.
 * @return The configured security configuration.
 * @throws Exception is throws if the configuration fails.
 */
protected HttpSecurity logout(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl(portalLogoutURL)
            .addLogoutHandler(getLogoutHandler())
            .logoutSuccessHandler(getLogoutSuccessHandler())
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .and();
}

@Bean
public UsernamePasswordPortalAuthenticationFilter getUsernamePasswordPortalAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
    UsernamePasswordPortalAuthenticationFilter customFilter = new UsernamePasswordPortalAuthenticationFilter();
    customFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
    return customFilter;
}
```

**`UsernamePasswordPortalAuthenticationFilter.java`**:

```
    @PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
    public class UsernamePasswordPortalAuthenticationFilter extends 
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Value("${captchaActive}")
    private boolean captchaActive;

    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager getAuthenticationManager() {
        return super.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        UsernamePasswordPortalAuthenticationToken authRequest = getAuthenticationTokenFromRequest(request);
        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
    }

    /**
     * Reads the UsernamePasswordPortalAuthenticationToken from the data of the request.
     *
     * @param request The request to read the data from.
     * @return The authentication token.
     * @throws AuthenticationException is thrown if the data cannot be read.
     */
    public UsernamePasswordPortalAuthenticationToken getAuthenticationTokenFromRequest(final HttpServletRequest request) throws AuthenticationException {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        String line = null;

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buf.append(line);
            }

            UsernamePasswordPortalAuthenticationToken loginDataWithCaptcha =
                new ObjectMapper().readValue(buf.toString(), UsernamePasswordPortalAuthenticationToken.class);

            if (this.captchaActive) {
                String answer = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("COLLPHIRCAPTCHA");

                List<CaptchaCookieDto> captchaCookieDtos;
                captchaCookieDtos = (List<CaptchaCookieDto>) request.getAttribute("captchaCookies");

                CaptchaCookieDto captchaCookieDto = captchaCookieDtos.stream().filter(captchaCookie -> captchaCookie.getUsername().equals(
                    loginDataWithCaptcha.getUsername())).findAny().orElse(null);

                if (captchaCookieDto != null && captchaCookieDto.getCounter() >= 2) {
                    if (answer.equals(loginDataWithCaptcha.getConfirmCaptcha())) {
                        return new ObjectMapper().readValue(loginDataWithCaptcha.loginDataToStringWithoutCaptcha(),
                            UsernamePasswordPortalAuthenticationToken.class);
                    } else {
                        throw new BadCredentialsException("invalid data");
                    }
                } else {
                    return new ObjectMapper().readValue(loginDataWithCaptcha.loginDataToStringWithoutCaptcha(),
                        UsernamePasswordPortalAuthenticationToken.class);
                }
            } else {
                return new ObjectMapper().readValue(loginDataWithCaptcha.loginDataToStringWithoutCaptcha(), UsernamePasswordPortalAuthenticationToken.class);
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("invalid data");
        }

    }

}
```

I tried changing the order of my two custom filters (`CORSFilter` and `CookieFilter`), or putting the `CORSFilter` somehwere else (`addFilterBefore` `SessionManagementFilter` does not work, if I do that, the login-call won't work because of the missing CORS-header) and almost everything else...

I also tried using the idea from the `authsuccesshandler` from https://www.baeldung.com/spring_redirect_after_login where I just get the requests `origin` header (which should be the frontend-URL `https://localhost:3000`) to redirect back to it:

```java
@Component
public class MyTestAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    public MyTestAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        super();
        setUseReferer(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication auth) throws IOException {
        LOG.info("onAuthenticationSuccess");
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

        handle(request, response, auth);
    }

    protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication auth) throws IOException {

        String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(request);

        if (response.isCommitted()) {
            LOG.info("Response has already been committed. Unable to redirect to " + targetUrl);
            return;
        }

        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
    }

    protected String determineTargetUrl(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getHeader("Origin");
    }
}
```

but still it doesn't work.

Also, if I try to debug the backend and set breakpoints inside of the `authsuccesshandler` and `authfailurehandler`, it still doesn't stop there. Shouldn't it stop there?

```java
.formLogin()
        .loginPage(c440_START_PAGE)
        .successHandler(getAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
        .failureHandler(getAuthenticationFailureHandler())
        .loginProcessingUrl(C440_LOGIN)
        .permitAll()
        .and();
```

I really don't understand where this redirect is happening and why it won't use my new `authsuccesshandler`.

**UPDATE 07.03.19:** It seems that the **`successhandler` isn't being called at all**, even if I deploy both frontend and backend at the same URL as a bundled WAR file which makes the login work again. Weird thing is, even if I remove the **`.formLogin()`** stuff from the configure method inside the `SecurityConfig` the login still works. So I guess it looks like all the magic is happening in the **`AuthenticationProvider`** which is being called in our custom **`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`**:

**`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`**

```
[...]
@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
    UsernamePasswordPortalAuthenticationToken authRequest = getAuthenticationTokenFromRequest(request);
    return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
}
[...]
```

**`AuthenticationProvider`:**

```
[...]
@Override
public CollphirAuthentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    if (authentication == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("authentication");
    }

    if (UsernamePasswordPortalAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication.getClass())) {
        UsernamePasswordPortalAuthenticationToken clientAuthentication = (UsernamePasswordPortalAuthenticationToken) authentication;

        CollphirUser user = getUserService().loginUser(
                clientAuthentication.getName(), clientAuthentication.getCredentials().toString(), clientAuthentication.getPortal(), clientAuthentication.getArbeitgeber());
        CollphirAuthentication auth = null;

        if (user == null || user.getBenutzerkennung() == null || user.getCOLRolle() == null) {
            LOG.info("authentication failed");
            Notification[] notifications = user.getNotifications();
            String msg = null;

            if (notifications != null && notifications[0] != null && notifications[0].getText() != null) {
                msg = notifications[0].getText();
            }

            throw new BadCredentialsException(msg);
        }
        Referenz arbeitgeberReference = getArbeitgeberReference(user, clientAuthentication.getPortal(), clientAuthentication.getArbeitgeber());

        auth = new CollphirAuthentication(user, arbeitgeberReference);
        auth.setArbeitgeber(getArbeitgeber( arbeitgeberReference));

        LOG.debug("is authenticated: " + auth.isAuthenticated());

        return auth;
    }

    throw new BadCredentialsException("type");
}
[...]
```

So my guess is: Somewhere inside the **`UsernamePasswordPortalAuthenticationFilter`** or **`AuthenticationProvider`** the redirect is being made. If I think about it, a redirect doesn't make sense at all in an AngularJS frontend where the call to the backend is being made via REST, right? Shouldn't the backend just send back a status code or something which the AngularJS controller can evaluate to change the state or display an error message?

It looks like the whole login process in this application is really weird. I can't imagine it is usual to not use the **`.formLogin()`** and **`.successHandler()`**? The thing is, I don't have a best practice example for an AngularJS frontend and Spring Security backend as comparison...

Comment: Theres just a GET-Request to https://localhost:8443/context after the call to https://localhost:8443/context/login (which retrurns a 302) nothing more...

Comment: Maybe issue with the browser? check if this helps
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43563899/5383945

Comment: @Jazib No, that's not it, but thanks!

Comment: @Vortilion Do you use Spring Boot? Did you check, if your configuration is executed at all?

Comment: @Vortilion:  Your question is really hard to read. Could you please clean up your question? If I understand your question right, your are logged in successfully, but you are wrong redirected. If this is right, then CORS configuration works fine, remove it from your question. Also your `AuthenticationProvider` works fine, remove it from your question.

Comment: @Vortilion But some important informations about the redirect are missing. What is the value of `c440_START_PAGE` and the value of `C440_LOGIN`. Also you need to provide `UsernamePasswordPortalAuthenticationFilter ` class configuration (in `getUsernamePasswordPortalAuthenticationFilter`). Did you add handlers?

Comment: @dur Added the information and removed the cors stuff. I just wanted to give as much info as possible, and as I've mentioned I'm quite new to Spring Security so I didn't really know what might be relevant and what not. Sorry... :-(

Comment: @dur Also, as I've said, the whole part 
`formLogin().loginPage(c440_START_PAGE).successHandler(getAuthenticationSuccessHandler()).failureHandler(getAuthenticationFailureHandler()).loginProcessingUrl(C440_LOGIN)` 
seems to be unnecessary and is not being called at all (including the successhandler and failurehandler), which confuses me. If I remove it the login still works (if deployed as one war).

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the Springs default AuthenticationSuccessHandler? I think that this handler just redirect to the application base path and it is not working if your frontend is at another context or URL. So you have to perform a redirect after an successfull login back to your frontend.

Take a look at this page: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-redirect-login

Here you find a few possibilities to handle that case.

Comment: Thanks. I took a look at it and tried editing my AuthenticationSuccessHandler, but it didnt change anything.... The weird thing is, if I try to login, it doesnt stop at my breakpoint in this SuccessHandler....